# Easeljs patterns - explain differences

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I have seen two different tutorials on Easeljs, one by David Rousset and one by Lee Brimelow. I am not sure which is better to use, and what the differences are. Example 1 (David Rousset):

```
(function (window) {
function Player(imgPlayer, x_start, x_end) {
    this.initialize(imgPlayer, x_start, x_end);
}
Player.prototype = new createjs.BitmapAnimation();

// public properties:

Player.prototype.alive = true;

// constructor:
Player.prototype.BitmapAnimation_initialize = Player.prototype.initialize; //unique to avoid overiding base class

var quaterFrameSize;

Player.prototype.initialize = function (imgPlayer, x_end) {
    var localSpriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
        images: [imgPlayer], //image to use
        frames: { width:64, height:64, regX:32, regY: 32 },
        animations: {
            walk: [0, 9, "walk", 4]
        }
    });

    createjs.SpriteSheetUtils.addFlippedFrames(localSpriteSheet, true, false, false);

    this.BitmapAnimation_initialize(localSpriteSheet);
    this.x_end = x_end;

    quaterFrameSize = this.spriteSheet.getFrame(0).rect.width / 4;

    // start playing the first sequence:
    this.gotoAndPlay("idle");     //animate
    this.isInIdleMode = true;

}

Player.prototype.tick = function () {
//specific tick function for the player
}

    window.Player = Player;
} (window));
```

and Example 2 (Lee Brimelow):

```
(function(window) {

function Player(){


    // Adding the easeljs bitmap as a property of Player:       
    this.view = new createjs.Bitmap("assets/pics/player1.png")

    // Setting som local parameters
    var height          = stage.canvas.height;
    var width           = stage.canvas.width;
    var playerRadius            = 70;
    var offset          = 200;
    var x               = 0;
    var y                   = 0;

    this.view.regX = this.view.regY = playerRadius;

    // Adding the tickfunction below
    this.view.onTick    = tick;



}

function tick(e) {

//

}

window.Player = Player;
})(window);
```

Just ingnore that one uses BitmapAnimation and one just a basic Bitmap.

In the Example1:

1) Would it be the same to replace the line:

```
Player.prototype.alive = true;
```

with:

```
this.alive = true;
```

2) What does the:

```
Player.prototype.BitmapAnimation_initialize = Player.prototype.initialize; //unique to avoid overiding base class
```

do, i don't understand the comment...

3) Is this line added to start the initilize function:

```
Player.prototype = new createjs.BitmapAnimation();
```

I am not sure what actually happens when new Player() is run in Example 1.

4) Setting the tick as a property of Player will mean that you have to call this tick function in your main tick function, isn't it better to use the inbuilt onTick event handler of the Ticker class in easljs (as done in example 2)?

Which of the patterns above are "best practice" and why?

Additionally, both of these patterns are dependent on a main.js that creates the Player object (and the Player object is set to a property of the window). To keep everything from the global scope or to be able to use this code on for instance a node.js would it be better to wrap the main.js in an object as well, in a similar matter, and pass this Main object in as a parameter to the function instead of the window?

Lets say you make this main js:

```
Main = {
init: function() {
    //set up and create Player
    var player = new Player;
},
//then adding som properties, variables to Main... for instance
propA: 0 
}
```

Is this possible/feasable?

Comment: It's personal preference. Pick one you understand and like and run with it. I'm voting to close as it's too broad and will be primarily opinions rather than specific facts for answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Difference between both patterns:**

The two patterns are (usually, if used as intended) not used for the same purposes.
The first pattern is for **inheritance** and the second pattern is for **MVC**. (google Model View Controller pattern).
Personally I prefere the first pattern, because it's also the pattern used by EaselJS internally, you might want to think about MVC in bigger projects, which EaselJS apps (usually) not are.

Also: With the second pattern you will most likely have to also use the first pattern at some point if you want to utilize MVC AND inheritance, and I personally have never seen a MVC project without inheritance. Personally I have never experienced any advantages in the MVC pattern  in JS/EaselJS projects (but there are probably plenty of people who don't share that point of view, and I agree with them in most other languages, but not JS).

---

**To answer your other questions:**

1. No, it would not be the same. If you wrote the `this.alive = true;` into the initialize-method then you'd have the same result throughout the runtime of your code, but strictly seen even that would be different from setting a prototype-property(but this goes deep into JS-internal functionality).
2. The `Player`-class 'inherits' from the `BitmapAnimation`, and the pattern (that is also used by EaselJS in this case) provides that every class features an `initialize`-method. So before the initialize-method is defined for the Player, the original initialize-method is 'saved' as `BitmapAnimation_initialize` and later called from within the new initialize-method, 15lines below.
3. That line basically 'injects'(or inherits...but strictly seen JS has no inheritance-model, at least not like Java, C#, AS3, ect...) all the functionality from `BitmapAnimation` to the `Player`, so when you create a new Player you can for example use: `myPlayer.gotoAndPlay('animation')` but `gotoAndPlay()` is actually a method from `BitmapAnimation`.
4. True, it'd be better to use `onTick..` which is called automatically if the object is a child of the stage, the `tick` might still be from an earlier version of EaselJS (not too sure though).

**Which pattern is 'best practice':**

I'd say, that the first pattern is (FOR EASELJS) best practice, because this is the pattern that EaselJS uses for its' own classes as well. (With some minor differences, like a namespace for example). For a huge project you might want to consider MVC.

Comment: Thanks @olsn, great answer. I did some more research on the onTick vs tick, and found that onTick is "Deprecated: In favour of the "tick" event. Will be removed in a future version.". I don't know why, it's a nice property. When it comes to question 1, I meant to set the this.alive property outside of the initialize method as a public property directly on the Player objec, but i guess that wouldn't work?

Comment: if you set it outside a method it will be a property of the `function (window) { ... }` so it will have no effect whatsoever, since this is an anonymous function, that you won't be able to address later. - the `.prototye.XXX` way will make it a "public" property, so when you create a player you can check for `myPlayer.isAlive` - also note, that "public" and "private" isn't something that JS currently supports on its' own.

Comment: What does the second example have to do with MVC? All I can see is the revealing module pattern.

Comment: Stricktly seen the code-example itself just mimes a View-Controller-Pattern, but you rarely see any explanations of that pattern without a Model - that's why I wrote MVC to not confuse him with a google search - But it is no Revealing Module pattern, as the RMP is a function returning the revealing-object (example here: http://blog.alexanderdickson.com/javascript-revealing-module-pattern), the 2nd example does not do that, any property of the 2nd example can be considered public.